# Where to get Dell Inspiron 1545 drivers for the Dell 1397 wlan minicard wireless card?

Tags: wireless, dell, broadcom

I cant seem to find the drivers for my Dell Wireless WLAN 1397 Minicard for ubuntu 11.04 andone know how i can get them and install them im sort of new to ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your connected by an Ethernet cable and open the terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T)

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot.